# Limitar a quantidade de caracteres de um campo select HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: html, css

Sei que através do atributo `maxlength`é possível limitar a quantidade de caracteres de um `input`.

A dúvida: Essa propriedade se aplica ao `select`, se não qual seria seu equivalente, ou como atingir o mesmo objetivo.

```html
<select maxlength="5">
  <option value="opcao" maxlength="5">123456789</option>
</select>
```

Note que no código acima o atributo não funciona, então como proceder?

Comment: Receio que não de para fazer o que você quer, a propriedade `maxlength`, se aplica ao valor do componente, mas no caso do `select`, o usuário não vai selecionar um valor não pré-definido. De certa forma, seria uma propriedade não utilizada.

Comment: Por que você precisa disso?

Comment: @Juliano ao selecionar uma das opções, a mesma ultrapassa seu espaço e se sobrepõe a "arrow", o fato é que certas palavras a letra fica "comida" ou cortada...

Comment: Você pode limitar o número máximo uma vez que é você que coloca o número em cada option. Não é o utilizador a preencher.

Comment: @JorgeB. obrigado pela atenção, Essas options vem de forma dinâmica, tens uma ideia, para eu limitar a quantidade de letras ?

Comment: Parece que o seu problema é que você quer cortar o texto que será apresentado na option. Ao invés de fazer isso você pode pensar em como reformular um texto muito grande.

Comment: @Juliano Sorry my english not is good but, u can show me any ideia, how i can solve my problem ?

Comment: Você quer cada `option` de um tamanho? Ou quem manda no tamanho é o `select`?

Comment: @renan Obrigado pela atenção, gostaria de limitar todos com 5 caracteres por exemplo.

Comment: @MagicHat podes fazer isso na linguagem que usas para apresentar de forma dinamica, não precisa de ser no HTML.

Comment: @JorgeB. entendo, tens uma ideia em js ?

Comment: @MagicHat depende de como você vai buscar os dados e onde. Dá para por algum código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode utilizar Javascript para isso:

```js
(function(){
  var selects = document.querySelectorAll('[data-limit]');
  
  // percorre a lista de selects
  [].forEach.call(selects, function(select){
    
    var limit = select.getAttribute('data-limit');
    
    // percorre a lista de options do select
    [].forEach.call(select.options, function(option){
      var text = option.innerHTML.substring(0, limit);
      option.innerHTML = text;
    });
  });
})();
```

```html
<select data-limit='5'>
  <option>123</option>
  <option>1234567890</option>
  <option>123456</option>
</select>

<select data-limit='2'>
  <option>4321</option>
  <option>1234567890</option>
  <option>123</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Se eu encontrar uma solução somente c/ html e css, eu edito essa resposta.

Comment: Ah muleke, zica eim, fico show... Era isso mesmo...vlw

Comment: @MagicHat pode aguardar por mais respostas, pode ser que tenha alguma solução melhor. Eu não curti muito essa, estou até procurando alguma alternativa "mais bonitinha". :D

Comment: Pra ser sincero acho que oferecer o caminho, já é de bom grado, melhorar fica a cargo de quem for usar. Claro que pessoas como vc, não se contentam com algo que talvez acreditem poder melhorar... Pra mim fico show, mas se tiver melhor  dou +2(se desse)kkkk vlw man

Comment: E mano num alterei nada, copiei colei... o bang encaixa em qualquer código...Pode acrescentar no seu framework....